# Prevent Logcat from automatically clearing

Tags: android, logcat

I am using Android Studio 1.2.2 and Logcat sometimes automatically clears itsself after my app crashes.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit Filter Configuration ->Add your package name

[image]

Answer (score 10):

yes, Because it filters Log of our application. And when app crashes LogCat has no app to filter.

Also remember that LogCat has previous messages that we can get again by setting NO FILTER to LogCat.[image: No Filter]

Just select No Filters. It will give your messages again :-)